# how to use local variable in other functions

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
var shuffle = function(x) {
    var deck = [];
    deck.push(x);

    return deck;
};

var Placemat = function() {
    var card1 = deck.shift();
    var card2 = deck.shift();
}
```

By returning deck in `shuffle()` like this, can I use it in `Placemat()`? If not, how can I do it?

Comment: I don't know about that username bro.

Comment: @Triptych--fair enough, but do you know the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could. But anytime you call `.shuffle()` you would overwrite that array, or more precisely, create a new instance. So if you want to keep that reference you could go like

```
var shuffle = (function() {
    var deck = [];

    return function(x) {
        deck.push(x);

        return deck;
    };
}());
```

Now `.shuffle()` closes over the `deck` by returning another function. So it could look like

```
var Placemat = function() {
    var myDeck = shuffle(5);

    shuffle(10);
    shuffle(15);

    var card1 = deck.shift();
    var card2 = deck.shift();
}
```

Even if that is probably not the greatest way to go. But I guess I don't even know what exactly you want to achieve there.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `myDeck.shift()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot you have to put them in the parameters or outside the function.

```
var shuffle = function(x) {
    var deck = [];
    deck.push(x);

    return deck;
};

 var Placemat = function(deck) {
    var card1 = deck.shift();
    var card2 = deck.shift();
}

or 

var deck = [];
var Placemat = function() {
    var card1 = deck.shift();
    car card2 = deck.shift();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the return value from `shuffle` in `Placemat`, but it will always be an array with a single item in it.

If you want to have a variable `deck` that contains multiple items, `deck` will need to be declared in an outer scope:

```
var deck = [];

var shuffle = function(x) {
    deck.push(x);
    return deck;
}

var Placemat = function() {
    var card1 = deck.shift();
    var card2 = deck.shift();
};
```

This way, both the `shuffle` function and `Placemat` are using the same variable `deck`.

Answer (score -1):

I found another solution:

```
var shuffle = function(deck,x) {
    var deck = [];
    deck.push(x);

    return deck;
};

var Placemat = function() {
    var newdeck = shuffle(deck,x)
    var card1 = newdeck.shift();
    var card2 = newdeck.shift();
}
```

This way I don't have to make `deck` a global variable. Thanks for the help everyone.